# Should the tags rdbms and relational-database be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

The abbreviation [rdbms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rdbms) is short for "relational database management system" which seems to be mean exactly the same thing as [relational-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relational-database).

There are 1,658 questions tagged [rdbms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rdbms); there are 4,643 questions tagged [relational-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relational-database); and there are 55 of those tagged with both.  The top users lists indicate that both the tags are 'valid'.

Shouldn't those two tags be merged?

The tag [database-theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-theory) has just 35 questions and no tag wiki. Coincidentally, the tag [relational-theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relational-theory) has also has 35 questions, and also has no tag wiki.

Comment: [tag:relational-model] is also a tag.

Comment: Suggested question name: `Should the tags rdbms and relational-database be coalesced?` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Comment: Not necessarily, but there might be room to wonder how accurately the tags are used.  In principle, I agree with Lyth that there are distinctions between [tag:relational-database] and [tag:rdbms] (and [tag:relational-model] and [tag:database-theory]), but whether everyone who's ever used any of them has recognized the distinctions and tagged accurately is another matter altogether.

Comment: Outer join on [rdbms] and [relational-database]

Answer (score -2):

Consider relationship between these tags:

- [database-theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-theory)
- [relational-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relational-model)
- [relational-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relational-database)
- [rdbms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rdbms)

It seems they are nicely ordered this way, from generic to specific, with rdbms for the management software itself.

Comment: As I've noted in an update to the main question, both the [tag:database-theory] and [tag:relational-model] coincidentally have the same number of questions (35), and neither has a tag wiki.  They're not particularly good tags.  Also, for the majority of questions where one of those is an appropriate tag, the subject of the question is likely to be 'too broad' or otherwise not directly related to programming.  I agree in principle with your observation; I'm not sure whether SO users in general understand the distinction.

Comment: I do see the reason for a distinction of the first two tags. But I fail to see an example where `rdbms` makes more sense then `relational-database`. If a specific product is targeted (which you seem to imply what the tag `rdbms` is about) then that product tag should be used. If no specific product is targeted (and the question is not about "SQL") then I don't see the benefit over having both of them

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it is my understanding that database management (storage, replication, even indexing to some extent) should be separated from relational database querying or modelling, with the latter being on `relational-database` side.

Comment: Any question about "the management software itself" will almost certainly be specific to a particular brand of software: Oracle, Postgres, SQL Server, whatnot. And there are existing tags for those.

Comment: and managing a rdbms may belong more to database.SE or superuser.SE

Comment: Every tag should be closely linked with the tasks of a software engineer... for 3 out of 4 of those tags, I can only think of DBA's and very academic centric that I find no use for SO.

Comment: Agree on avoiding academic and highly dba centric topics, as we have better SE for that. Also I would like to see the tags standardized with common `database-` prefix. This case, I would name it `database-rdbms` and huh - actually that is the only one that I would keep out of the 4 given.